How to read and write with cairomm png stream?
I'm saving a Cairo::ImageSurface as part of a binary file. Writing pixels from surface->get_data() works fine, however it produces a much larger file compared to when I write it with surface->write_to_png(std::string name). So I'm trying to use surface->write_to_png_stream(const SlotWriteFunc &write_func); and Cairo::ImageSurface::create_from_png_stream(const SlotReadFunc &read_func);
Initially, the Cairo::Surface::SlotWriteFunc callback made sense to me, it is called several times while writing the surface and provides parameters const unsigned char* as data and unsigned int as length, but Cairo::Surface::SlotReadFunc confuses me, as it also provides an unsigned int that determines how much data it wants to read. Why isn't it a unsigned int&, so that I can tell the length based on the file? This leads me to a conclusion that I don't understand the SlotWriteFunc neither.
Please explain how to use SlotWriteFunc and SlotReadFunc.
Thank you for your help.
The following example writes to the file fine, but throws an error where I call create_from_png_stream:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cairomm/cairomm.h>


class PNGStream {
public:

    std::fstream *file;
    

    Cairo::ErrorStatus write(const unsigned char *data, unsigned int length) {
        std::cout << length << std::endl;

        file->write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&length), sizeof(length));
        file->write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data), length);

        return Cairo::ErrorStatus::CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

    Cairo::ErrorStatus read(unsigned char *data, unsigned int length) {
        std::cout << length << std::endl;

        // I'm not sure, what comes here

        return Cairo::ErrorStatus::CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::fstream file;
    PNGStream png_stream;
    png_stream.file = &file;
    auto surface = Cairo::ImageSurface::create(Cairo::Surface::Format::ARGB32, 1920, 1080);
    auto cr = Cairo::Context::create(surface);
    
    cr->set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0);
    cr->paint();
    file.open("test.png", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    surface->write_to_png_stream(sigc::mem_fun(png_stream, &PNGStream::write));
    file.close();
    
    file.open("test.png", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    auto surface2 = Cairo::ImageSurface::create_from_png_stream(sigc::mem_fun(png_stream, &PNGStream::read)); //error
    file.close();
    
    return 0;
}


I have no answer, but this just looks suspicious so I do have some C++ advice: std::fstream *file; You probably want to giveyour PNGStream a constructor that accepts an std::istream& so you can construct it like std::fstream file_stream{"test.png"}; PNGStream png_stream{file_stream};. And do not call open/close manually let the the stream constructor/destructor take care of that.

Thank you, I will follow the best practice

PNG files have a known format, it consists of chunks, with each chunk prefixed by its length, cairo can read it chunk by chunk, until the read fails indicating the end of file.
As for the code you write, you should just read length bytes from the stream, if the read was unsuccessful then the file stream will have the error flag set.
    Cairo::ErrorStatus read(unsigned char *data, unsigned int length) {
        std::cout << length << std::endl;

        file->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), length);
        if (file->fail()) // read failed
        {
          return Cairo::ErrorStatus::CAIRO_STATUS_READ_ERROR;
        }
        return Cairo::ErrorStatus::CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }

This will work if you have a file stream of size exactly equal to that of a png, but if you have anything else "packed" in the same file (like embedded resources) then you need to count how many bytes were read and manually limit the bytes read, ie: fail if more bytes are requested.
the writer side should just write instead of read
    Cairo::ErrorStatus write(const unsigned char* data, unsigned int length) {
        std::cout << length << std::endl;

        file->write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data), length);
        if (file->fail()) // write failed
        {
          return Cairo::ErrorStatus::CAIRO_STATUS_WRITE_ERROR;
        }
        return Cairo::ErrorStatus::CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }


Thank you, it works like charm.
